# blank page when refreshing in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, router, react-router-redux

when i navigate from /home to /dashboard,router is working fine but when i navigate from /home to /profile:id, router navigates me to that profile page which is also working fine,but when i refresh it,then it becomes blank page and does not give me any 404 or redirects back to home page,i am using

`react-router: "^4.2.0",`
`react-router-dom: "^4.2.2",`
`react-router-redux: "5.0.0-alpha.6",`

So,how to get rid of blank page and if url is at /profile/5,and then on refresh page gets navigate back to home page or anything that should be appropriate,please help?

> index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
            <Route component={Page404} />
        </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app-site')
);
```

> App.js

```
<Switch>
    <Route path={`/login`} component={LoginMember} />
    <Route path={`/registermember`} component={SignUp} />
    <Authentication component={AuthenticateRoute} />
    <Route component={Page404} />
</Switch>

const AuthenticateRoute = ({ match }) => (
 <Switch>
    <Authentication path={`${match.url}`} component={MainApp} />
    <Route component={Page404} />
 </Switch>
);
```

> MainApp

```
<Switch>                
    <Route path={`/home`} component={Home} />
    <Route path={`/profile/:id`} component={Profile} />
    <Route component={Page404} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: What's the back-end in? Node, php? Most probably it's the back-end routing. When you refresh the page you are accessing your app on a "/profile" route, which the back-end first intercepts and doesn't know how to handle if you only handled the root uri "/".

Comment: @raul-reneem i dont think,it is a problem of backend....

Answer (score 7):

### The problem we are solving

When building and deploying an app to a server, sometimes refreshing the page results in a blank page. I discovered that the solution to this issue was in the package.json file.

### Your package.json currently

Do the following change:

By default, your package.json might contain something like this:

`"homepage": "./"` or this `"homepage": "."`

### Changes required to solve the issue in package.json

To fix the issue, simply change it to:

```
"homepage": "/"
```

This will ensure that everything loads correctly, including store, context, components, redux, etc.

I hope this helps anyone facing the same problem. Here are some additional details that might be useful:

This solution is for react router v6.

#### Further explaining and interesting facts in my quest to solve this mystery...

The problem mostly appears in nested routes. I tested it in non-nested routes and everything worked as expected, so nested routes seem to be a factor here.

By nested routes, I mean routes that are inside a different file from the original route. For example, in my app, I had a frontpage for clients and a dashboard for managing products shown on the frontpage. My file structure looked like this:

```
-src (Folder)
--App.js (Contains two main routes of /frontpages and /dashboard, which render the files from the routes folder)
--Routes (Folder)
---Dashboard.jsx (Contains nested dashboard routes)
---Frontpages.jsx (Contains nested frontpage routes)
--Components (Folder)
---All the files that get rendered in the routes folder components.
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code,

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
  <Route component={Page404} />
</Switch>
```

`<Route path="/" component={App} />` it causing to render the `App` component for every route.So,if you refreshing the page,`Page404` will  not get a chance to render it.

Solution :

Put `exact`   for `/`.

```
<Route exact  path="/" component={App} />
```

Comment: yes,because you have defined any other router except these two.So,if you tried another apart from `/` these then you will always get 404.

Comment: see i first renders index.js if find '/',then it goes to component 'App', and in 'App' if Auth true,then it is passed to MainApp,so please guide me the correct way,what i need to do for correct implementation

Answer (score 0):

This is because react is not able to locate the history of the url which is been naviagted by users.
Basically react property will search for the url which is saved in history but here developer didn't use that.
To solve that follow these three steps.
import the use like this import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
assign to a variable and
use that main div/router which all the component is wrapped inside it

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this and my issue was in package.json, and I specified the homepage in my package.json, for example:

```
.
.
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath"
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved a similarly weird issue. I was running a simple HTML and vanilla JS and website in Visual Studio Code's Live Extension.

Initially on startup I would always get black screen and only after a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) would I get the contents of the website on the screen.

Simply clearing the browser cache solved the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34490195)