# When refreshing any specific route it shows blank page

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

The home page refreshes successfully. But for any other route when I refresh the page goes blank.

Example:

```
.../view/5f9ad1c453db51de5e52f94d
.../browse/movies/
```

And here the settings for above:

1- Nginx configuration

```
.
.
.
root /var/www/html/build;
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
index index.html;
.
.
.
```

2- React

```
<Router history={history}>
<Nav />
<div className="container mx-auto padding-m">
    <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/browse/movies/*" component={Browse} />
        <Route path="/view/:id" component={View} />
        <Route path="/category/:id" component={Category} />
    </Switch>
</div>
<Footer />
```

3- Versions

```
----
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
"react-router-dom": "latest",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3",
----
```

And I already tried to add `"homepage": "./"` to `package.json`

I did not try to eject and change webpack settings,

Any advice?

I already checked the following answer but it didn't work for me:
[blank page when refreshing in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189880/blank-page-when-refreshing-in-react-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my issue was in package.json, and I specified the homepage in my package.json, for example:

```
.
.
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath"
.
.
```

and solved my issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case changing `"homepage": "./"` to `"homepage": "/"` in my package.json did the trick.